# Как в .Net Core узнать текущее состояние любого процесса?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core

Имеется список процессов, по этому списку необходимо пройтись и получить для каждого процесса его состояние т.е.
runned, sleep, zombie, и т.д.
В Linux имеется множество состояний:

```
R  Выполняется
S Спит, ожидая прерывания
D Ожидает в сне, непрерываемом диском
Z Зомби
T Остановлен(по сигналу) или остановлен из-за трассировки(до Linux 2.6.33)
t Остановлен из-за трассировки(после Linux 2.6.33)
W Происходит замещение страниц(только до Linux 2.6.0)
X Мёртв(с Linux 2.6.0)
x Мёртв(только в Linux 2.6.33 по 3.13)
K Пробудился, чтобы умереть(только в Linux 2.6.33 по 3.13)
W Пробуждается(только в Linux 2.6.33 по 3.13)
P Припаркован(только в Linux 3.9 по 3.13)
```

Как я могу получить нечто подобное в Windows?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов ну может тогда и пример приведете решающий эту задачу? мне не нужен тупо Responding, нужно подробное состояние, было бы это в гугле я бы нашел!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Windows нет понятия "состояние процесса", но можно вывести состояние основного потока процесса:

```
var prs = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process pr in prs)
{
    ProcessThread th = pr.Threads[0];
    using (th)
    {

        Console.Write(pr.ProcessName + ": ");
        Console.Write(th.ThreadState.ToString());


        if (th.ThreadState == ThreadState.Wait)
            Console.Write(" (" + th.WaitReason.ToString() + ")");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

См. [ProcessThread.ThreadState Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processthread.threadstate?view=netframework-4.7.2)